# Is it possible to set an agent by branch in Jenkins declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I think the answer is no but is it possible for a declarative Jenkins pipeline to set the agent based on a git branch. It doesn't appear that you can use the **when** block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just write regular groovy `if {} else {}` statements before `pipeline {}`. Something like that

```
def agentLabel
if (BRANCH_NAME == "foo") {
    agentLabel = "fooAgent"
} else {
    agentLabel = "barAgent"
}

pipeline {
    agent { label agentLabel }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: @grayaii it is a variable without explicit type declaration. See [Variable definition](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_variable_definition) from Groovy language specification.

Comment: for me BRANCH_NAME is not working. it says "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BRANCH_NAME for class: WorkflowScript" Does BRANCH_NAME require separate plugin.?env.GIT_BRANCH is also not working.

Comment: @pravingaikwad07 is your job a Multibranch Pipeline? The variable is exposed only to that type of job. See [Branches and Pull Requests](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/)